# Correct way to say "each person"?

Tags: translation

If I wanted to say, "Each person's monthly rent is $650", what is the correct way to say it?

每个月各人的房租是六五十钱。

Or

一人的每个月房租是六五十钱。

Or something else if neither is right

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you specify "per month" in your English sentence?

Comment: It was a typing mistake; I fixed it

Comment: say 六百五十元 instead of 六五十钱... Unlike English, we don't say 'six fifty' in Chinese for 650.

Comment: 每个人的 **月** 租是650元 would be the exact equivalent of your English sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"Each person" here means "每个人", such as,

```
每个人的房租月租金是650元。
```

BTW: Your translation is understandable except for 六五十钱 which can't be understood correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I would say

> 每人每月房租650元

Its meaning is simple and clean.

Answer (score 2):

> "每个月各人的房租是六五十钱。"
>   "一人的每个月房租是六五十钱。"

“六五十钱” is not a correct way to say. Therefore, you should substitute that by "六百五十美元" or in a more common form "650$". After that, the first one sounds ok, but the second one doesn't sound right. Place that "的" in your sentence behind “每个月”. 
The way I say it will be:

> 每人每月的房租为650$。

It contains a rhythm in it since “每” is used twice.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, there are two ways to say it:

1. 每人每月650元 - general speaking
2. 650块钱一人一个月 - emphasis the price, more oral

Answer (score 1):

房租每人每月六百五十美元！  六五钱 is ungrammatical in Mandarin Chinese.

Comment: Starting the sentence with 房租 makes what you wrote hard to understand too

Comment: lol, well.....this is real chinese way in real life to say it....  grammar is important on paper but in real life, just like English, no one really care about grammars.

Comment: @罗伯特漂流记 Um.. that's not true at all in regards to the last statement in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Each person's monthly rent is $650

If you want to use a sentence it would be something along the line with:

> 每个人一个月的房租是$650
>
> $650 can be read as 六百五十 元/块/刀
>
> you can say 一个人/每人 instead of saying 每个人
>
> you can say 每个月/每月 instead of saying 一个月

If you want to express it as a phrase, like used on a sign or something, in this situation in Chinese words like "的" or "是" would normally be omitted, it would be something like:

> 每人每月房租$650

How to read currency:

If in a context where there is no confusion of what currency you are referring to, you can just read the dollar sign as 元/块.

If you want to emphasise the unit your are referring to is dollar, you can use 刀 in no-formal conversation. Using 刀 is not valid Chinese but it's widely used in China nowadays since the country is been more exposed to foreign culture. However, note that language and education authorities does not encourage such usage.

Otherwise you can use 美元 if it's USD, or 澳元 for AUD and so on so forth.

Answer (score 0):

每人 or 每个人 is appropriate. Sometimes people will use 各个人。